# `npm install` goes to dead in China

Tags: node.js, networking, npm

It halts when using `npm` to install dependencies for `node.js` applications. **But** works without any problem outside China. Who know ways to make it works beside `VPN/SSH channel`.

```
$ npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
# ... ... halt for hours and hours ... march 2014
# ... ... halts times after times ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps it will work with the [European registry](http://shapeshed.com/using-the-european-npm-mirror/)?

```
$ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.eu
$ npm install
```

Unless that is blocked also?

Comment: Worked for me too just now, was struggling otherwise.

Answer (score 14):

There is a [Chinese registry](http://cnpmjs.org/) now too:

```
$ npm config set registry http://r.cnpmjs.org
$ npm install
```

It syncs with registry.npmjs.org.

Comment: This worked much more easily for me than using the EU registry

Answer (score 13):

Another mirror in China is  https://registry.npm.taobao.org/.

```
$ npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org/
$ npm install
```

Comment: This is the same answer as below isnt it.

Comment: taobao's mirror is faster than cnpmjs.org

Comment: @AlexanderYao It may be faster, but I am in UK, why npm with all new projects I am creating offers always this China servers as prefered?

Answer (score 7):

just use taobao's mirror

```
npm install -g cnpm --registry=http://registry.npm.taobao.org
cnpm install -g your-lib-name
```

Comment: Please explain `cnpm`.

Comment: cnpm is very buggy, for example, it doesn't run post install script from npm package